# Angular template drive forms: Reset values AND status (pristine, dirty, touched, invalid)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my template driven form there are many groups and fields inside it. I can successfully reset field/model values of a specific ngModelGroup but the status [invalid, touched, dirty] of custom components are unchanged. Here is the code:

1) HTML

```
<div ngModelGroup="personGroup" #personGroup="ngModelGroup">
    <app-input-text name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" label="Your Name" required></app-input-text>

    <app-input-text name="age" [(ngModel)]="age" label="Your Age" required></app-input-text>

    <div class="example-container">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
            <input matInput name="country" placeholder="Your Country" [(ngModel)]="country" required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

2) TS

```
export class AppComponent {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  country: string;

  @ViewChild("personForm")
  private personForm: NgForm;

  reset() {
    this.personForm.controls['personGroup'].reset();

  }
}
```

When I click on "Reset", values are cleared but component status does not change.

The app-input-text implements ControlValueAccessor and seems to be ok except on this behavior.

How do I reset values AND custom component status?

Here is the StackBliz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g2r9g5

Thanks in advance!